# django help loop in formset only returns last index in forms.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

trying to loop over formset forms inside forms.py but it only returns the last index of formset not all of them.
forms.py:

```
class MyModelFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
def clean(self):
    super(MyModelFormSet, self).clean()

    totalforms = self.total_form_count() #to get number of forms in formset

    for form in self.forms:
        for n in range(totalforms):
            d = self[n].cleaned_data['debit'] # if i use  manullay self[0], self[1] it works
        if d == 100:
            raise forms.ValidationError('debit is 100!')
        return d
```

Comment: your are storing your "self[n].cleaned_data['debit']" in "d" every time, and d is constant not an array or dict. Just change it to fix.

Comment: Oh Thank you ! how I did not think about that :) your solution solved my issue thanks a lot :)

Comment: @amezamr how about give me like on my comment.

Answer (score 0):

finally solved with NVS comment
Here is the updated code:
first need to setup a list and then append to that list

```
class MyModelFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
def clean(self):
    super(MyModelFormSet, self).clean()

    totalforms = self.total_form_count() #to get number of forms in formset
    ds = []
    for form in self.forms:
        for n in range(totalforms):
            d = self[n].cleaned_data['debit']
            ds.append(d)
        if 100 in ds:
            raise forms.ValidationError('debit is 100!')
        return d
```